# Is there a way make a reusable shape object?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm using LeafletJS to make a custom lab layout map and I plan to put in some rectangle layers to show whether or not areas are in use. Currently I have a working test case using coordinates to define each shape, but is there a way I can create a standard sized shape object which can be called and fed a single coordinate to center itself on?

Here is the current code from my Angular controller if it helps.

```js
function showMap() {
  var map = L.map('mapid', {
      crs: L.CRS.Simple,
      maxZoom: 4,
      attributionControl: false
    }).setView([0, 0], 1),
    southWest = map.unproject([0, 4096], map.getMaxZoom()),
    northEast = map.unproject([4096, 0], map.getMaxZoom()),
    bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

  L.tileLayer('images/4231/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    minZoom: 1,
    maxZoom: 4,
    center: [0, 0],
    noWrap: true,
    bounds: bounds
  }).addTo(map);

  var testBench = [{
    number: "1A1",
    coord1: "-48.6",
    coord2: "6",
    coord3: "-81.4",
    coord4: "71",
    inUse: true
  }, {
    number: "1A2",
    coord1: "-48.5",
    coord2: "71",
    coord3: "-81",
    coord4: "137",
    inUse: false
  }, {
    number: "1A3",
    coord1: "-48.5",
    coord2: "137",
    coord3: "-81",
    coord4: "202",
    inUse: true
  }];

  angular.forEach(testBench, function(item, index) {
    var location = [
        [item.coord1, item.coord2],
        [item.coord3, item.coord4]
      ],
      color;
    switch (item.inUse) {
      case true:
        color = "red"
        break;
      case false:
        color = "green"
        break;
    }
    L.rectangle(location, {
      color: color,
      weight: 1
    }).bindPopup("Bench Number is: " + item.number).addTo(map);
  })
  map.setMaxBounds(bounds);
}
```

Eventually the bench info will be pulled from a DB rather than a variable and there will be hundreds of benches, so I'm looking to streamline the positioning layout as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way I can create a standard sized shape object which can be called and fed a single coordinate to center itself on?

In Leaflet, no.

Leaflet vector features, or `L.Path`s (`L.Polyline`s and `L.Polygon`s) are defined by their coordinates, not by their centroid and a series of offsets to that centroid.

You might want to implement a simple [Factory design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)) to create regularly-shaped features giving only a center point, though.